# C cannot declare valid int pointer

Tags: c, pointers, declaration, dereference

I'm working on a program to get the day of the year to its equivalent day and month. For example, day 60 of year 1988 corresponds to the 29th of the 2nd month (February).

The function uses int pointers to assign the resultant month and day:

```
void month_day(int year, int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday);
```

I'm running across a weird error, getting a segmentation fault error. After debugging, I've seen that the problem is with `*pday`. Despite defining it, C is somehow unable to fetch a valid adress (it assigns adress `0x0`) so I get a segmentation error when trying to assign to pointer's adress:

```
int main() {
int *pmonth, *pday;
month_day(1988, 60, pmonth, pday);
}

void month_day(int year, int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday) {
  /* some calculations on yearday */
  
  /* Error takes place here because `pday` isn't a valid adress */
  *pday = yearday;
}
```

I have been able to overcome this issue by defining an `int` instead of a pointer and passing its address to the function instead of a pointer, as in:

```
int *pmonth, pday;
month_day(1988, 60, pmonth, &pday);
```

Somehow the problem is only with the 2nd pointer and as I said, it happens because pointer `*pday` is assigned an invalid adress after its definition.

However, I really cannot explain why does the error takes place in the first place.

Could someone please explain me why does this happen?

In case it's necessary, the complete code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void month_day(int year, int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday);

int main() {
  int *pmonth, *pday;
  month_day(1988, 60, pmonth, pday);
  printf("%d %d\n", *pmonth, *pday);
}

static char arrnonleap[] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
static char arrleap[] = {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
static char *daytab[] = {arrnonleap, arrleap};

/* month_day: set month, day from day of year */
void month_day(int year, int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday) {
  int i, leap;

  if (year < 0 || yearday < 0 || yearday > 366)
    printf("Invalid year and/or yearday\n");
  
  leap = year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0;
  for (i = 1; yearday > (*(daytab + leap))[i]; i++)
    yearday -= (*(daytab + leap))[i];
  *pmonth = i;
  *pday = yearday;
}
```

Comment: `int *pmonth, *pday;` have not been initialised, yet you dereference them.

Comment: Pointers can only be dereferenced if they point to something that was allocated... so just declaring a pointer does not mean you can assign to its referent. If you avoided uninitialised variables, this would be clear: you'd have to assign some address to the pointer, and you know `NULL`/`0` is not usable, so then what? You have to assign the address of some automatically or dynamically allocated `int`, as you saw.

Comment: ...and if you mean it seems to work OK despite not doing that also with the other pointer, that just means that undefined behaviour is undefined. Reading an uninitialised variable is UB, and dereferencing an invalid pointer is UB, and you do both here. So your program can do nothing, seem somehow to work perfectly, or blow up the Moon. That is why you need to code attentively and avoid UB at all times. C is not a language where the compiler stops you shooting your foot off.

Comment: I tried initializing the pointers as in: `int *pmonth=0, *pday=0;`. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Read what I wrote again... To assign through the pointer, it must point **at an object**. A pointer holding `0`/`NULL` or any other arbitrary number does not _point at an object_. You need to declare/allocate an actual `int` that really exists and point at it. Pointers can only point at something or nothing, where "nothing" means `NULL`/`0`, and if they point at nothing, then how can you assign something to nothing?? UB makes things even worse, but treat uninitialised as "nothing" here, and don't dereference (e.g. assign thru) a pointer until it _is pointing at something_.

Comment: Change the `main()` content to `int pmonth, pday; month_day(1988, 60, &pmonth, &pday); printf("%d %d\n", pmonth, pday);`

Comment: Yes, I have seen that using ints instead of pointers solved the issue, but I wanted to understand why it didn't work with pointers or how could I make it work using pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(void) {
  int *pmonth, *pday;
  month_day(1988, 60, pmonth, pday);
  printf("%d %d\n", *pmonth, *pday);
}
```

you need to initialize the pointer with valid memory location big enough to accommodate the `int`

```
int main(void) {
  int month,day;
  int *pmonth = &month, *pday = &day;
  month_day(1988, 60, pmonth, pday);
  printf("%d %d\n", *pmonth, *pday);
}
```

or just simple

```
int main(void) {
  int month, day;
  month_day(1988, 60, &month, &day);
  printf("%d %d\n", month, day);
}
```

```
int main(void) {
  int *pmonth = malloc(sizeof(*pmonth)), *pday = = malloc(sizeof(*pday));
  month_day(1988, 60, pmonth, pday);
  printf("%d %d\n", *pmonth, *pday);
  free(pmonth);
  free(pday);
}
```